# What is the grep equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a text file with the line 'I like elephants'.
If I cat the said file and the pipe it to 'grep elephants', I get the entire line "I like elephants".

How do I achieve this functionality in Python with re? 
Ive been trying the following:

```
test = re.search('elephants', 'I like elephants.\nThey are nice')
test.group(0)
```

I get only the word 'elephants' and not the whole sentence as the output.

How do I get the entire sentence? 
Thank you.

Comment: Split into lines and get those items where `elephants` is `in` the `line` string. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/fyYw5r).

Comment: what, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: With regex, you'd need to match all chars on a line, `re.search('.*elephants.*', 'I like elephants.\nThey are nice')`. However, this approach is inefficient.

Comment: Aaaah I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the `in` keyword to check for your substring:

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'elephant' in line:
            print(line)
```

Or, if you had a string `s` with `\n` characters:

```
for line in s.split('\n'):
    if 'elephant' in line:
        print(line)
```

Your regex only prints `elephant` because that's what it captured: exactly your regex string. If you were to try the following regex instead:

```
test = re.search(r'(.*?elephants.*?)\n', 'I like elephants.\nThey are nice')
```

Then you'd have results for `test.group(0)` and `test.group(1)` which include the whole line before and after the elephants.

```
In [22]: test.group(0)
Out[22]: 'I like elephants.\n'
```

That's the whole captured string.

```
In [23]: test.group(1)
Out[23]: 'I like elephants.'
```

That's just the capture group (string between parentheses).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! 
I would also like to know where I was going wrong in the regex if you happen to know.

Comment: @Zohair sure, added an explanation; see updated answer!

Comment: That’s really helpful Pedro! Thank you so much!