# Check if a file has certain strings

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have some files (file1), in some servers (group: myservers), which should look like this:

```
search www.mysebsite.com
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 1.2.3.5
```

This is an example of what this file should look like:
The first line is mandatory ("search www.mysebsite.com").
The second and the third lines are mandatory as well, but the ips can change (although they should all be like this: *.*.*.*).

I've being researching to implement some tasks using Ansible to check if the files are properly configured. I don't want to change any file, only check and output if the files are not ok or not.
I know I can use *ansible.builtin.lineinfile* to check it, but I still haven't managed to find out how to achieve this.
Can you help please?

Comment: Since Ansible is mostly used as Configuration Management Tool there is no need to check if a file is properly configured. Just declare the Desired State and make sure that the file is in that state. Still under some circumstances one may need to [to search for a string in a remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250240/). So does it answer your question?

Comment: I read this question as testing patterns, not a configuration. It's expressed clearly `"first line is mandatory, but the ips can change ... to check if the files are properly configured"`. See the audit framework. It is a valid problem, I think . Don't you want to revoke the close requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[myservers]
test_11
test_13
```

Create a dictionary of what you want to audit

```yaml
  audit:
    files:
      /etc/resolv.conf:
        patterns:
          - '^search example.com$'
          - '^nameserver \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$'
      /etc/rc.conf:
        patterns:
          - '^sshd_enable="YES"$'
          - '^syslogd_flags="-ss"$'
```

---

Note: The order of the patterns is mandatory. The tests will succeed if the first two lines of the files match the sequence of patterns. For example,

```bash
shell> cat /etc/rc.conf
sshd_enable="YES"
syslogd_flags="-ss"
```

```bash
shell> cat /etc/resolv.conf
search example.com
nameserver 10.1.0.1
```

---

Declare the directory at the controller where the files will be stored

```yaml
  my_dest: /tmp/ansible/myservers
```

[*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#ansible-builtin-fetch-module-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) the files

```yaml
    - fetch:
        src: "{{ item.key }}"
        dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
      loop: "{{ audit.files|dict2items }}"
```

Take a look at the fetched files

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/ansible/myservers
/tmp/ansible/myservers
├── test_11
│   └── etc
│       ├── rc.conf
│       └── resolv.conf
└── test_13
    └── etc
        ├── rc.conf
        └── resolv.conf

4 directories, 4 files
```

Audit the files. Create the dictionary *host_files_results* in the loop

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        host_files_results: "{{ host_files_results|default({})|
                                combine(host_file_dict|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ audit.files|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
      vars:
        host_file_path: "{{ my_dest }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item.key }}"
        host_file_lines: "{{ lookup('file', host_file_path).splitlines() }}"
        host_file_result: |
          [{% for pattern in item.value.patterns %}
          {{ host_file_lines[loop.index0] is regex pattern }},
          {% endfor %}]
        host_file_dict: "{ {{ item.key }}: {{ host_file_result|from_yaml is all }} }"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_11] => 
  host_files_results:
    /etc/rc.conf: true
    /etc/resolv.conf: true
ok: [test_13] => 
  host_files_results:
    /etc/rc.conf: true
    /etc/resolv.conf: true
```

Declare the dictionary *audit_files* that aggregates *host_files_results*

```yaml
  audit_files: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                        zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                            map('extract', hostvars, 'host_files_results'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  audit_files:
    test_11:
      /etc/rc.conf: true
      /etc/resolv.conf: true
    test_13:
      /etc/rc.conf: true
      /etc/resolv.conf: true
```

Evaluate the audit results

```yaml
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: audit_files
        - assert:
            that: "{{ audit_files|json_query('*.*')|flatten is all }}"
            fail_msg: "[ERR] Audit of files failed. [TODO: list failed]"
            success_msg: "[OK]  Audit of files passed."
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
 msg: '[OK]  Audit of files passed.'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: myservers

  vars:

    my_dest: /tmp/ansible/myservers

    audit:
      files:
        /etc/resolv.conf:
          patterns:
            - '^search example.com$'
            - '^nameserver \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$'
        /etc/rc.conf:
          patterns:
            - '^sshd_enable="YES"$'
            - '^syslogd_flags="-ss"$'

    audit_files: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                          zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                              map('extract', hostvars, 'host_files_results'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        src: "{{ item.key }}"
        dest: "{{ my_dest }}"
      loop: "{{ audit.files|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"

    - set_fact:
        host_files_results: "{{ host_files_results|default({})|
                                combine(host_file_dict|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ audit.files|dict2items }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.key }}"
      vars:
        host_file_path: "{{ my_dest }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item.key }}"
        host_file_lines: "{{ lookup('file', host_file_path).splitlines() }}"
        host_file_result: |
          [{% for pattern in item.value.patterns %}
          {{ host_file_lines[loop.index0] is regex pattern }},
          {% endfor %}]
        host_file_dict: "{ {{ item.key }}: {{ host_file_result|from_yaml is all }} }"

    - debug:
        var: host_files_results

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: audit_files
        - assert:
            that: "{{ audit_files|json_query('*.*')|flatten is all }}"
            fail_msg: "[ERR] Audit of files failed. [TODO: list failed]"
            success_msg: "[OK]  Audit of files passed."
      run_once: true
```

Comment: An interesting approach for auditing only certain or explicit configuration properties instead of full configuration files.

Comment: FWIW. See for example [Ubuntu 20 CIS](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/UBUNTU20-CIS) it's a mix of configuring and testing.

Answer (score 0):

> *... implement some tasks using Ansible to check if the files are properly configured. I don't want to change any file, only check and output if the files are not ok or not.*

Since Ansible is mostly used as Configuration Management Tool there is no need to check (before) if a file is properly configured. Just declare the Desired State and make sure that the file is in that state. As this is approach is working with [Validating: `check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html) too, if interested in a Configuration Check or an Audit it could be implemented simply as follow:

**`resolv.conf`** as is it should be

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search example.com
nameserver 192.0.2.1
```

**`hosts.ini`**

```ini
[test]
test.example.com NS_IP=192.0.2.1
```

**`resolv.conf.j2`** template

```yaml
# Generated by NetworkManager
search {{ DOMAIN }}
nameserver {{ NS_IP }}
```

A minimal example playbook for Configuration Check in order to audit the config

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # Ansible v2.9 and later
    DOMAIN: "{{ inventory_hostname.split('.', 1) | last }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Check configuration (file)
    template:
      src: resolv.conf.j2
      dest: resolv.conf
    check_mode: true # will never change existing config
    register: result

  - name: Config change
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.changed }}"
```

will result for no changes into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Check configuration (file)] ******
ok: [test.example.com]

TASK [Config change] *******************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: false
```

or for changes into

```yaml
TASK [Check configuration (file)] ******
changed: [test.example.com]

TASK [Config change] *******************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: true
```

and depending on what's in the config file.

If one is interested in an other message text and need to invert the output therefore, just use `msg: "{{ not result.changed }}"` as it will report an false if true and true if false.

**Further Reading**

Using Ansible [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), [variables in inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory), the [`template` module (to) Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) and [Enforcing `check_mode` on tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks) makes it extremely simply to prevent Configuration Drift.

And as a reference for getting the search domain, [Ansible: How to get hostname without domain name?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17139/6017).

Comment: I tried this approach. Both files resolv.conf.j2 and resolv.conf are different. But I am getting msg: true. Shouldn't I get false if the files are not alike?

Comment: If `resolv.conf.j2` and `resolv.conf` are different you'll get an `changed: true` which is correct so far as it means "Are they different?: true". If you like to get a message "Are the files are the same?" you would need to invert the boolean value.

Comment: Yes, I'd like some info if the file doesn't contain the mentioned strings : The file is not ok. Or if the files are alike: "The file is ok". Can you help?

Comment: "_if the file doesn't contain the mentioned strings : The file is not ok._", that is what the example is doing already. However, if you like to invert the message output just use `msg: "{{ not result.changed }}"` as it will report an false if true and true if false.

Comment: ok, you are correct. ANyway I could use regex or a wild card to the ips? To make it like this format: *.*.*.*

Comment: For templates I am not sure, I would need to find this out by myself before and since it is adding significant (for me unnecessary) complexity to such a case. Maybe you can just go with the [other here provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75453482/6771046) as they is addressing regex in IP already.