# How to extract the line from a file containing text

Tags: ansible, pattern-matching, extract

I am trying to find if the files of a type contain a string and want to extract the entire matching line, from the file

To get the list of files containing the text, I am trying to use the `find` module.  And that is working.  But I haven't found a way to extract all the lines and assign them to an array containing the string, from the file

```
- name: Verify that string out of memory exists in file /var/log/messages
  find:
  paths: /var/log/
  patterns: 
    - messages.*
    - messages
  file_type: file
  use_regex: true
  read_whole_file: true
  contains: "Out of memory"
  register: strfound
```

I tried to see if I could use slurp, but these are large files and slurp also displays the entire file on the screen in base64 format, so did not continue with that option.

Is there a way to have another task that will extract the lines from the list of files found in the above task and put them in an array ?

Comment: I understand that you like to parse remote logs. Because of the nature of your Use Case it is recommended to do it remote and distributed. By doing this there will be no need to transfer logs over the wire, in example to the Control Node and process the data there. Furthermore, instead of working with full log files, one can just collect the final result list. So I assume [How to search for a string in a remote file using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250240/) will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this module.  Where do I save this file?  I was trying to determine from the links in that answer, but not clear

Comment: Usually under your project folder, just in folder `library`. It should already(?) be configured as default search path in `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: @U880D - Thanks.  The module worked.  I am using it with the output of the above `find` command - and that also is working.  One question - when I run the playbook that contains the `pygrep:` task, it adds that as a log message to `/var.log/messages` file.  It may be Linux behavior or a custom module behavior.  Just wondering, if you know, and if I could "NOT" have it get added to the messages file on the server.  e.g. `"Dec 19 11:49:43 server1 ansible-pygrep: Invoked with path=/var/log/messages search_string=Out of memory",`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good to hear. "_it get added to the messages file on the server_", that's interesting and I haven't noticed such yet, so I would need to do further debugging and development on this.

Comment: @U880D -  If you put the below link in the answer, I can accept it.  Also, it seems the ansible request getting added to messages log - is linux functionality.  I saw other ansible playbook executions also added there.   If you know how to stop ansible from adding the command to this file - `/var/log/messages`,  please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the parsing issues, slurping [doubles the amount of required RAM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html#notes), which is something unwanted in case of large logs.

If you don't mind to use `fgrep`, a quick solution would look like this (paths modified for testing):

```yaml
    - name: Verify that string out of memory exists in file /var/log/messages
      find:
        paths: "/Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/scratches/messages"
        patterns:
          - messages.*
          - messages
        file_type: file
        use_regex: true
        read_whole_file: true
        contains: "{{ string_to_search }}"
      register: strfound

    - name: Extract the lines
      when: strfound is defined and strfound.files
      block:
        - name: Grep the files
          command: "fgrep '{{ string_to_search }}' '{{ item.path }}'"
          register: search_results
          loop: "{{ strfound.files }}"
          loop_control:
            label: "{{ item.path }}"

        - name: Collect the found lines
          set_fact:
            found_lines: "{{ found_lines | default([]) + found_file.stdout_lines }}"
          loop: "{{ search_results.results }}"
          loop_control:
            loop_var: "found_file"
            label: "{{ found_file.item.path }}"

        - name: Log the final result
          debug:
            var: found_lines
```

Which results in the following:

```
TASK [Collect the found lines] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/scratches/messages/messages.log)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/Users/alexander/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/scratches/messages/messages.with.token.log)

TASK [Log the final result] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "found_lines": [
        "  contains: \"Out of memory\"",
        "another \"Out of memory\" entry",
        "and one more \"Out of memory\" entry"
    ]
}
```